# jQuery - compare indexOF from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

I would like to apologise in advance if my question is stupid, but I am very new to jQuery. What I am trying to achieve is to compare two variables. The first one will be getting its value from divs. The second one will be an array. I will be very grateful if someone can give me hints where my mistake is. Thank you in advance.

Best regards, George

```js
var User  = $('.User').text();
var Lucky_Names = ["Florence", "Brenda", "Steven"];
console.log(Lucky_Names);

if(User.indexOf(Lucky_Names) >= 1){
  alert("Congratulations, we found a match.");
}
else{
  alert("We couldn't find a match.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="User">Mark Watts</div>
<div class="User">Wanda Hathaway</div>
<div class="User">Ann Bailes</div>
<div class="User">Hal Piccirillo</div>
<div class="User">Richard Branson</div>
<div class="User">Jeffery Robison</div>
<div class="User">Christina Hammons</div>
<div class="User">Helen Clarke</div>
<div class="User">Terra Herrera</div>
<div class="User">Steven Rhodes</div>
<br>
<div style="color:red">PS: All the names in this list were randomly generated.</div>
```

Comment: .text() returns only first matching selector text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to loop through each `.User` element using `jQuery.each`, and it will be easier to make the array a regex or creating one from it like this:

```js
var Lucky_Names = ["Florence", "Brenda", "Steven"];

var regex = new RegExp(Lucky_Names.join('|')); // regex: /Florence|Brenda|Steven/ (must be escaped if there is special characters)

$('.User').each(function() {                   // for each .User element
  var text = $(this).text();                   // get the text
  if(regex.test(text)) {                       // check if the regex matchs
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="User">Mark Watts</div>
<div class="User">Wanda Hathaway</div>
<div class="User">Ann Bailes</div>
<div class="User">Hal Piccirillo</div>
<div class="User">Florence Branson</div>
<div class="User">Jeffery Robison</div>
<div class="User">Christina Hammons</div>
<div class="User">Helen Clarke</div>
<div class="User">Terra Herrera</div>
<div class="User">Steven Rhodes</div>
<br>
<div style="color:red">PS: All the names in this list were randomly generated.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I found it very efficient and it worked instantaneously. I am very grateful for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `User.indexOf(Lucky_Names)`.

**EDIT**: Further, your `User` will be the input, whereas `Lucky_Users` contains 3 elements. You can alternatively use `Lucky_Names.indexOf(User) > -1`

I believe what you're trying to achieve is find `User` position in `Lucky_Names`

You need to provide index with `Lucky_Names`

```
var position=-1;
for(var i=0;i<Lucky_Names.length;i++) {
  if(Lucky_Names[i] === User) {
    position=i;
  }
}
console.log(position)
```

If `User` matches any of `Lucky_Names`, position will be it's index in `Lucky_Names`, otherwise it'll be `-1`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will definitely try to implement this idea as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`jQuery.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to iterate 
 `.User` elements, `.some()`, `.indexOf()` to filter `.textContent` of element.

```js
var Lucky_Names = ["Florence", "Brenda", "Steven"];
var matches = $.grep($(".User"), function(user) {
  return Lucky_Names.some(function(prop) {
  return user.textContent.indexOf(prop) > -1
  });
});

if (matches.length) {
  // do stuff
  $.each(matches, function() {
    this.style.color = "green"
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="User">Mark Watts</div>
<div class="User">Wanda Hathaway</div>
<div class="User">Ann Bailes</div>
<div class="User">Hal Piccirillo</div>
<div class="User">Richard Branson</div>
<div class="User">Jeffery Robison</div>
<div class="User">Christina Hammons</div>
<div class="User">Helen Clarke</div>
<div class="User">Terra Herrera</div>
<div class="User">Steven Rhodes</div>
<br>
<div style="color:red">PS: All the names in this list were randomly generated.</div>
```

You can alternatively use `.filter()`

```js
var Lucky_Names = ["Florence", "Brenda", "Steven"];
var matches = $(".User").filter(function(index, user) {
  return Lucky_Names.some(function(prop) {
  return user.textContent.indexOf(prop) > -1
  });
});

if (matches.length) {
  // do stuff
  matches.each(function() {
    this.style.color = "green"
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="User">Mark Watts</div>
<div class="User">Wanda Hathaway</div>
<div class="User">Ann Bailes</div>
<div class="User">Hal Piccirillo</div>
<div class="User">Richard Branson</div>
<div class="User">Jeffery Robison</div>
<div class="User">Christina Hammons</div>
<div class="User">Helen Clarke</div>
<div class="User">Terra Herrera</div>
<div class="User">Steven Rhodes</div>
<br>
<div style="color:red">PS: All the names in this list were randomly generated.</div>
```

Comment: Oh god not again, not you! Haha!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, the God again. We ain't going nowhere. Not at a computer that can check precisely though conveys approach. May need some adjustments

Comment: @guest271314 Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely try to use this approach in my next exercise.

Answer (score 2):

`$('.User').text()` will return all the names concatenated in one string, like this:

```
"Mark WattsWanda HathawayAnn BailesHal PiccirilloRichard BransonJeffery RobisonChristina HammonsHelen ClarkeTerra HerreraSteven Rhodes"
```

To find if this string contains any name from `Lucky_Names`:

```
var User  = $('.User').text();
var Lucky_Names = ["Florence", "Brenda", "Steven"];
console.log(Lucky_Names);

var _foundFlag = false;
Lucky_Names.forEach( function (d) {
    if (User.indexOf(d) > -1) //Note that 0 is also a positive match
        _foundFlag = true;
})

if (_foundFlag) {
    alert("Congratulations, we found a match.");   
} else {
    alert("We couldn't find a match.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I looked at you, but I found an easier one bellow in the comments. However, I am really grateful for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This could solve your problem + also alert which users were lucky. Since you are new to jQuery and also probably to Javascript, I'll try to explain what I've done.

1. Declared the variables `users`, `luckyNames` and `luckyUsers` as a `const` (constant value, because it will never be reassigned) [MDN Docs - const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).
2. Convert the results of `$('.User')` selector to an array by using `Array.from(...)` [MDN Docs - Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
3. I'm using a `map` function to create a new array with the results of applied action to each item inside the `users` array [MDN Docs - map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Also check out [MDN Docs - arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to understand the `user => {...}`
4. Afterwards I'm applying a `filter` function which will filter for me the lucky users. This happens inside the function, where I check if the  the firstname (applied a splitting by whitespace here to get it) is inside my `luckyNames` array [MDN Docs - filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
5. Finally I check if the length of my `luckyUsers` array (which contains only the filtered matches) is greater than 0.
6. To alert everything nicely, I'm using the template literals which allow me to embed expressions [MDN Docs - template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
7. Inside the template literals I'm using a `join(...)` to display the matched names separated by a `,` and a whitespace [MDN Docs - join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
8. To see how `join(...)` is working, just change/add a name which is in the list.

```js
const users = Array.from($('.User'));
const luckyNames = ["Florence", "Brenda", "Steven"];

const luckyUsers = users.map(user => {
  return user.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/, '');
}).filter(user => {
  return luckyNames.indexOf(user.split(' ')[0]) > -1;
});

if(luckyUsers.length > 0){
  alert(`Congratulations, we found a match: ${luckyUsers.join(', ')}`);
} else{
  alert("We couldn't find a match.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="User">Mark Watts</div>
<div class="User">Wanda Hathaway</div>
<div class="User">Ann Bailes</div>
<div class="User">Hal Piccirillo</div>
<div class="User">Richard Branson</div>
<div class="User">Jeffery Robison</div>
<div class="User">Christina Hammons</div>
<div class="User">Helen Clarke</div>
<div class="User">Terra Herrera</div>
<div class="User">Steven Rhodes</div>
<br>
<div style="color:red">PS: All the names in this list were randomly generated.</div>
```

Comment: I am really grateful for the detailed answer. I found a lot of things that I was missing. Thank you once more!